# Android start service after installing app without starting the App itself

Tags: android, service

In an interview recently, the interview asked if it is possible to start service after just installing the app without starting it?

Is it possible to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not supposed to be possible.

Apps are installed in a "stopped state", the same state that they are in after the user presses "Force Stop" on the app's page in Settings. While in that "stopped state", it takes an explicit `Intent` to cause any of that app's code to run. In most apps, that means that the user taps the home screen launcher icon for the app.

Comment: Even if the Stopped State wouldn't exist, I can't recall any way to do so, can you?

Comment: @JonZarate: Oh, I can think of a few. For example, the old malware that we had in Android 2.x would register receivers for every broadcast that they could think of, just to get control automatically eventually and be able to start their service and do whatever malicious stuff they wanted.

Comment: That was so obvious, I can't believe I just asked that. I mixed the permission system with that. I thought a developer wouldn't be able to do it since the permission hasn't been granted, but that's only for the *dangerous* permissions, so your *stopped state* is right.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can. I don't know if it is enough with the receiver android.intent.action.PACKAGE_INSTALL because I always thought that was related to other app installs. But you can capture the BOOT event, or the connectivity change event or something like that to start a service or whatever you want.

Comment: The app doesn't have permissions to get notified before at least 1 execution, check CommonsWare's answer.

Comment: Cool I didn't know that